# Hadoop DataNode won't use remote IPC Server adress

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, virtual-machine

For a "fast" Proof-of-concept I wanted to set up a mini Hadoop 0.18 cluster, by connecting two virtual machines, which I found configured in pseudo-distributed mode at [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vm-setup).

On my *hadoop-vm-1* I start a full cluster with master nodes and slave DataNode and TaskTracker on that machine.
Then I took the second VM as *hadoop-vm-2* and wanted it to host a 2nd DataNode and TaskTracker which would connect to *hadoop-vm-1* and add to this cluster.

Unfortunately, I can't start the 2nd DataNode, because it want's to connect to a local IPC server. This is the place where I would expect it to connect to *hadoop-vm-1*. The log writes as follows:

> 2013-02-07 19:55:29,954 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: /192.168.17.135:9000. Already tried 9 time(s).
>   2013-02-07 19:55:29,958 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Call failed on local exception
>   ..
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Instead of the IP 192.168.17.135 (which is *hadoop-vm-2*), 192.168.17.134 from *hadoop-vm-1* should have been used.

I think I configured the slave's hadoop-site.xxml correctly:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-vm-1/</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>hadoop-vm-1:9001</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

And of course I configured the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hadoop-vm-2.localdomain hadoop-vm-2
192.168.17.134 hadoop-vm-1
```

Any Ideas? thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: Indeed my gut feeling was right and my configuration was indeed ignored.

The [preconfigured VM](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vm-setup) from YAHOO has some obscure, additional config directory. This overwrites all configuration from the "conf" directory - even if you start the cluster manually and don't use the supplied tutorial start scripts.

So I removed the directory and put a symbol link with the same name which points to the conf directory. Now it works as expected. phew :-)

Answer (score 0):

The content of the /etc/hosts file should look like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  hadoop-vm-1
192.168.0.101 hadoop-vm-1
192.168.0.100 hadoop-vm-2
```

Check this [blog](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/whatswrong-datanode-on-remote-machine.html) and it's comments for more details. Also, in pseudo-distributed mode all the daemons would be running in their own JVM and on a single node. For 1+ nodes, it's fully distributed mode. More about the different modes [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/quickstart.html).

Also, there are multiple ways of setting up a Hadoop cluster.

1) Download all the relevant frameworks from Apache and manually set them up. Here ([1](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/), [2](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)) are some nice tutorials for the same. This approach requires some effort, but there a lot is learnt.

2) Use [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cloudera-manager.html) to automate the installation process of Hadoop and other related frameworks like Hive, HBase, ZooKeeper etc. There are a couple of other companies which provide automatic installation like [HDP](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.1/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1.html) from HortonWorks. Most of the things are automated and hidden behind the UI.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't help. I already had everything in place what is being recommended by your blog post, including tested ssh connection, open ports etc.